# Why does Solve lock up when trying to solve the quadratic equation with large integers?

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, diophantine-equations

Why does [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) lock up when trying to solve the equation

```
Solve[(x^2+y^2)+(x+y)==2^511 && x>0 && y>0,{x,y},Integers]
```

It works up `2^185`, but at higher powers of `2`, it seems to stop processing. The program says it's running, but there is no solution after running overnight. Running Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 32-bit OS.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I quickly get solutions for `2^257` (V11.3.0, macos).

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo - it should be 2^511

Comment: Probably it's combinatorial blowup. `n = 185` gives 32 solutions but `n = 257` already gives 1024. Might be more work and memory to store the symbolics than your CPU can handle.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think the reasons probably have to do with number theory.  `n = 323` produces 8192 solutions in 2.3s and `n = 325` produces only 128 solutions in 500s.  The memory growth is quite low. I think for `n = 511`, you just have to wait long enough, and I can't predict how long that is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a guess:
The Diophantine problem
$$ x^2+y^2+x+y=a$$
is equivalent, via $u=2x+1,v=2y+1$ to finding the odd solutions to
$$u^2+v^2=2+4a \,.$$
Whether `Solve` makes this transformation or not, 
solving the Pythagorean equation can be done from the prime factorization of $2+4a$.
How long `Solve` takes thus might depend on how long it takes to factor $2+4a$.

This is not hard to verify:

```
Block[{FactorInteger = (Print["FactorInteger"[##]]; Abort[]) &},
 PrintTemporary@Dynamic@Clock@Infinity;
 Print[2 + 4 2^325];
 Solve[(x^2 + y^2) + (x + y) == 2^325 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, Integers] // AbsoluteTiming
 ]
```

> ```
>   2734063405978764905465627783897026706691461788616515545532213258012441248999219\
>    90402939147127881730
>
> FactorInteger[
>   2734063405978764905465627783897026706691461788616515545532213258012441248999219\
>    90402939147127881730]
>
> $Aborted
> ```

Well, it turns out it takes about 500 sec. to factor `2 + 4 * 2^325`, which is about how long it takes the `Solve` above to run.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be exactly what is happening. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user63373 You're welcome. :)